# update text field after certain interval

Tags: java, swing

I am updating text field after certain time.

Here is my code:

```
ActionListener task = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                    tip1.setText(ad1.tip1());
                    tip2.setText(ad1.tip2());
                    tip3.setText(ad1.tip3());
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
          }
    };

        new javax.swing.Timer(1000, task).start();
```

my application respose very slow using this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** This is not a correct solution.

You need to throw it onto the EDT.  You are not supposed to change your Swing interface on any thread other than EDT.

```
try {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            tip1.setText(ad1.tip1());
            tip2.setText(ad1.tip2());
            tip3.setText(ad1.tip3());
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
    });
}
```

Sun has a few great [tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) on this subject.

Comment: I was under the impression that using the Swing timer would put it in the EDT.

Comment: Indeed, this answer is not correct.  Timers are appropriate for this, and using Invoke Later should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The timer code looks unsuspicious. Without knowing further details, the only possible culprit is

```
update.addActionListener(task);
```

What is `update` and how often will the listener/task be fired (in addition to the executions triggered via the timer)?

Comment: code is editted ..
the tetfield should be updated after 1 sec